# how do you determine the total time spend using an ID (that is not unique) and timestamp column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've tried the following to get the total time spent for that visitor, but I'm unable to get this to work. Event_time is the timestamp and visit_id is the ID (which is not unique and will populate multiple times).

```
SELECT
visit_id,
SUM(DATEDIFF(second, LAG(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY event_time), event_time)) AS total_time_spent
FROM events_over;
GROUP BY visit_id;
```

when I try to run this, I see the following error:

> Window function [LAG(EVENTS.EVENT_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY
> EVENTS.VISIT_ID ORDER BY EVENTS.EVENT_TIME ASC NULLS LAST)] may not
> appear inside an aggregate function.

Comment: Try to move the SUM function into a subquery or a common table expression (CTE) and then perform the LAG function in the outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a window function inside an aggregate function as the message says. This one should work:

```
SELECT visit_id, SUM(time_diff) as total_time_spent FROM (
SELECT
visit_id,
DATEDIFF(second, LAG(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY visit_id ORDER BY event_time), event_time) time_diff
FROM events_over )
GROUP BY visit_id;
```